# Desktop Notification-Tide Sdk

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, tidesdk

Can it Possible to generate a desktop notification when an event occurs

For example suppose I create a desktop-remainder application for my desktop.

I need to create a alarm notification,about the task, when time of schedule arrives

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Here's some sample code I have used that has been working well for me:

```
function showNotify(title, message) {
  var notification = Ti.Notification.createNotification({
    'title': title || 'No Title',
    'message': message || 'No Message',
    'timeout': 10
  });
  notification.show();
}

showNotify("The Title", "The Message");
```

Answer (score 1):

Please checkout the documentations for tidesdk. There is Ti.Notification apis which provides exactly the stuff you need.

http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/api/Ti.Notification